# SUMing based on two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

First post so sorry!
I have:

| PARTICIPANT | VALUE | RULE | PERIOD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JAMES | 0 | RULE 1 | 2022-12-1 |
| JAMES | 0 | RULE 1 | 2022-01-1 |
| JAMES | 1 | RULE 1 | 2022-02-1 |
| JAMES | 1 | RULE 2 | 2022-12-1 |
| JAMES | 1 | RULE 2 | 2022-01-1 |
| JAMES | 1 | RULE 2 | 2022-02-1 |

I want:

| PARTICIPANT | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| JAMES | 1 |

I tried:

```
SELECT [PARTICIPANT], SUM([VALUE]), [Period]
FROM (
SELECT [PARTICIPANT], [VALUE], [RULE], [Period]
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [RULE]='RULE 1'
UNION
SELECT [PARTICIPANT], [VALUE], [RULE], [Period]
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [RULE]='RULE 2'
) AS [T1]
GROUP BY [Participant], [Period]
```

I have four columns [Participant, Value, Rule and Period]
There are only two types of [Rule].

I want to Select the participant's value for each Period only if the value of Rule 1 is >= to value of Rule 2.

I am not sure how to denote the comparison since each participant has multiple periods and each period may or may not have both rules.

I also want to sum the value of the selected periods by participant to perform functions on later.

Comment: What have you tried ? also please provide example data and expected result from that data. Also Rule is reserved keyword: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: So, correct me if I am wrong (as there is literally no sample data or expected results to help us reach a conclusion), but you want *all* the rows for a `Participant` where `value`, when `Rule` has a value of `1`, is greater or equal `value` for the *same* `Participant`, when `Rule` has a value of `2`?

Comment: Otherwise, if your statement *"Rule 1 is >= to value of Rule 2."* to be interpreted literally this'll never be true; `1` is *always* less than `2`, or your column `Rule` has some kind of "tuple" value; as it would be to denote it's number *and* it's value.

Comment: In short, we *need* sample data and expected results, as well as your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do you good

```
SELECT [TR1].[PARTICIPANT], SUM([TR1].[VALUE]) AS [VALUE], [TR1].[Period]
FROM 
(
    SELECT [PARTICIPANT], SUM([VALUE]) AS [VALUE], [RULE], [Period]
    FROM [TABLE]
    WHERE [RULE]='RULE 1'
    GROUP BY [PARTICIPANT], [RULE], [Period]
) [TR1] LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT [PARTICIPANT], SUM([VALUE]) AS [VALUE], [RULE], [Period]
    FROM [TABLE]
    WHERE [RULE]='RULE 2'
    GROUP BY [PARTICIPANT], [RULE], [Period]
) [TR2]
ON [TR1].[PARTICIPANT] = [TR2].[PARTICIPANT] AND 
    [TR1].[Period] = [TR2].[Period]
WHERE [TR1].[VALUE] >= COALESCE([TR2].[VALUE], 0)
GROUP BY [TR1].[PARTICIPANT], [TR1].[Period]
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up only grouping outside the join!

Comment: Totally forgot about the Grouping, Pleased to help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want conditional aggregation per `PERIOD`, then group again only by `PARTICIPANT`

```sql
SELECT
  t.PARTICIPANT,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Rule1 >= t.Rule2 THEN 1 END) Rule1MoreThan
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.PARTICIPANT,
      t.PERIOD,
      SUM(CASE WHEN t.[RULE] = 'RULE 1' THEN t.VALUE END) Rule1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN t.[RULE] = 'RULE 2' THEN t.VALUE END) Rule2
    FROM [TABLE] t
    GROUP BY
      t.PARTICIPANT,
      t.PERIOD
) t
GROUP BY
  t.PARTICIPANT;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6b115cf6b401f3a96624273bef4be1ea)

Comment: I am selecting the value when the value for Rule 1 is greater or equal than the value for Rule 2 for the same time period. For my example there is only one time period when that is true so thats why the result is 1. For other participants it might be true 4 times so my final value would be "4"

Comment: So you want to know how *many* periods the sum is greater? Or do you want to see each period individually? Sample data and expected results for these edge cases would help

Comment: How many periods Rule 1 is greater. I do have that info?

Comment: So something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6b115cf6b401f3a96624273bef4be1ea

Comment: I think this could also work but I went with the answer above. Thanks!